# To get a valid link extracted after scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

After scraping the web page, a "huff" link appears, but it is too long and some links are not connected. Fortunately, it is consistent, so I think I can extract the last link.

This is the link I get after scraping.

> https://ta.tokopedia.com/promo/v1/clicks/8a-
> ...SKIP...
> ob=23&t=desktop&dv=desktop&keywords=ipad&management_type=1&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokopedia.com%2Fapplewatchstuff%2Fapple-ipad-air-4-4th-gen-2020-10-9-inch-64gb-wifi-only-bnib-rose-gold%3Fsrc%3Dtopads&src=search&is_search=1&page=2

In the last string, that's what I want, but I think I need some encoding.

> https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokopedia.com%2Fapplewatchstuff%2Fapple-ipad-air-4-4th-gen-2020-10-9-inch-64gb-wifi-only-bnib-rose-gold%3Fsrc%3Dtopads&src=search&is_search=1&page=2

All the links I get show the same behavior.How can I get it correctly?

This is my code I am running

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = open_webdriver()
    url = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/search?navsource=home&page=2&q=ipad%20&st=product'
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.select('div.css-7fmtuv')
   
    for item in items:
        a_tag = item.select_one('a')
        title = a_tag['title']
        link = a_tag['href']
        price = a_tag.select_one('div.css-rhd610').text
        print(title, link, price)
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting and what is the output you are getting..? Also, how can i reproduce the problem..?

Comment: @AjaySinghRana,   I think you just run my code, btw I got the answer what I want.

Comment: congrats...it's always relaxing to find anwers...Hoooray..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that

```
for item in items:
    a_tag = item.select_one('a')
    title = a_tag['title']
    link_obj = a_tag['href']
    price = a_tag.select_one('div.css-rhd610').text
    # ----------------
    query = urlsplit(link_obj).query
    params = parse_qs(query)
    if 'r' in params.keys():
        link = params['r'][0]
    else:
        link = link_obj
    print(title, link, price)
```

```
iPad Air 4 2020 10.9 inch 64Gb Wifi Only https://www.tokopedia.com/modernapple/ipad-air-4-2020-10-9-inch-64gb-wifi-only-space-grey?src=topads Rp8.590.000
Apple iPad 8 2020 32GB/128GB Wifi Only Garansi 1 Tahun https://www.tokopedia.com/wahgadget/apple-ipad-8-2020-32gb-128gb-wifi-only-garansi-1-tahun-32gb-wifi-only-gray-inter?src=topads Rp5.400.000
Apple iPad Pro 3rd Gen 12.9&#34; inch 2018 Wifi+Cellular 64GB Gray Silver https://www.tokopedia.com/chocoapple/apple-ipad-pro-3rd-gen-12-9-inch-2018-wifi-cellular-64gb-gray-silver-silver?src=topads Rp15.200.000
iPad 8 2020 10.2 inch 128GB WIFI NEW https://www.tokopedia.com/modernapple/ipad-8-2020-10-2-inch-128gb-wifi-new-grey?src=topads Rp6.985.000
...
```